# Как объединить несколько Excel файлов в один?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, оптимизация, обработка-данных

Нужно объединить несколько прайс-листов в виде Excel файлов в один. Все .xlsx файлы с прайс-листами одинаковы по структуре: в первой строке шапка, дальше данные, количество столбцов одинаковое. Наименования товаров в итоговом файле должны идти в алфавитном порядке. Рядом с каждым наименованием товара должно быть название таблицы, из которой он взят.

Весь код что имеется на данный момент лишь объединяет все фалы в один:

```
import os
import panda as pd
cwd = os.path.abspath('C:\\Project')
files = os.listdir(cwd)


all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df = pd.read_excel(file)
        all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)
all_data.head()
status = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
all_data_st = pd.merge(all_data, status, how='left')
all_data_st.head()
all_data_st.to_excel('res.xlsx')
```

Как разобраться с остальным, идей нет вообще, поэтому прошу помощи.

Comment: `df.sort_values(['column_name'], ascending=[True])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path(r"C:\Project")

df = (pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f).assign(file_name=f.stem)
                 for f in data_dir.glob("*.xlsx")],
                ignore_index=True)
        .sort_values("<здесь указать наименования столбца с наименованием товаров>"))
```

Некоторые пояснения:

- `data_dir.glob("*.xlsx")` - итератор по все Excel файлам в директории
  `C:\Project`
- `.assign(file_name=f.stem)` - добавит к каждому прочитанному фрейму столбец `file_name` с наименованием файла (без расширения)
- `pd.concat(...)` - объединит (вертикально) все фреймы в один большой
- `.sort_values(<article_name_column_name>)` - отсортирует результат по столбцу `<здесь указать наименования столбца с наименованием товаров>`